# Laravel 5: Calling routes internally

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way, in Laravel 5, to call routes internally/programmatically from within the application? I've found a lot of tutorials for Laravel 4, but I cannot find the information for version 5.

Comment: Are you asking how you can consume your own routes within your application? I.E. inside of a controller get the result of a route? Are these JSON endpooints?

Comment: You don't have to. You can instantiate your controller and call the method

Comment: @Geckob posted the correct answer. Out of curiosity, why would you need to do this?

Comment: To embed the return as a child of a larger return.

Answer (score 22):

Using laravel 5.5, this method worked for me:

```
$req = Request::create('/my/url', 'POST', $params);
$res = app()->handle($req);
$responseBody = $res->getContent();
// or if you want the response to be json format  
// $responseBody = json_decode($res->getContent(), true);
```

Source:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-dispatch

***note:** maybe you will have issue if the route you're trying to access
has authentication middleware and you're not providing the right credentials.
to avoid this, be sure to set the correct headers required so that the request is processed normally (eg `Authorisation bearer ...`).

**UPDATE**: i've tried this method with laravel 8 and it works but if you're using PHP version 8.0 you might need to call `opcache_reset();` before this line `$req = Request::create('/my/url', 'POST', $params);` to avoid an error.

see [guzzlehttp/guzzle dosn't work after update php to php 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033643/guzzlehttp-guzzle-dosnt-work-after-update-php-to-php-8) for more info

Comment: I am trying out this approach, but i can't get the POST data sent under $params.

Answer (score 16):

You may try something like this:

```
// GET Request
$request = Request::create('/some/url/1', 'GET');
$response = Route::dispatch($request);

// POST Request
$request = Request::create('/some/url/1', 'POST', Request::all());
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

Comment: The Route::dispatch does not seem to work properly when calling from an Artisan command!

However @erwan's answer works well in this case: `$response = app()->handle($request);`

Comment: @ArnovanOordt 's suggestion to use `app()->handle()` rather than `Route::dispatch()` is the solution if you are running into an issue where the wrong instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request` is being injected to your middleware.

Comment: Agree with @ArnovanOordt info RE: calling from an Artisan command. `app()->handle($request)` is the solution

Answer (score 7):

You can actually call the controller that associates to that route instead of 'calling' the route internally.

For example:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/getUser', 'UserController@getUser');
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller {

   public function getUser($id){

      return \App\User::find($id);

   };
}
```

Instead of calling `/getUser` route, you can actually call `UserController@getUser` instead.

```
$ctrl = new \App\Http\Controllers\UserController();
$ctrl->getUser(1);
```

This is the same as `calling` the route internally if that what you mean. Hope that helps

Comment: How would that work for routes that are looking for Input data? i.e., a POST route.

Comment: Any thoughts, @geckob?

Comment: @vcardillo Same thing. But pass some parameters to the function to mimic the post bosy

Comment: Laravel does a lot of things internally do dispatch a route, far beyond simply creating a controller instance and calling a method, so you will face a lot of issues doing it this way. The correct answer is from @The Alpha

Answer (score 4):

```
// this code based on laravel 5.8
// I tried to solve this using guzzle first . but i found guzzle cant help me while I 
//am using same port. so below is the answer
// you may pass your params and other authentication related data while calling the 
//end point
public function profile(){

//    '/api/user/1' is my api end please put your one
// 
$req = Request::create('/api/user/1', 'GET',[ // you may pass this without this array
        'HTTP_Accept' => 'application/json', 
        'Content-type' => 'application/json'
        ]);
$res = app()->handle($req);
$responseBody = json_decode($res->getContent()); // convert to json object using 
json_decode and used getcontent() for getting content from response 
return response()->json(['msg' =>$responseBody ], 200); // return json data with 
//status code 200
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these answers worked for me: they would either not accept query parameters, or could not use the existing app() instance (needed for config & .env vars).

I want to call routes internally because I'm writing console commands to interface with my app's API.

Here's what I did that works well for me:

```php
<?php // We're using Laravel 5.3 here.

namespace App\Console;

use App\MyModel;
use App\MyOtherModel;
use App\Http\Controllers\MyController;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'mycommand
                            {variable1} : First variable
                            {variable2} : Another variable';

    public function handle()
    {
        // Set any required headers. I'm spoofing an AJAX request:
        request()->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        // Set your query data for the route:
        request()->merge([
            'variable1' => $this->argument('variable1'),
            'variable2'  => $this->argument('variable2'),
        ]);

        // Instantiate your controller and its dependencies:
        $response = (new MyController)->put(new MyModel, new MyOtherModel);

        // Do whatever you want with the response:
        var_dump($response->getStatusCode()); // 200, 404, etc.
        var_dump($response->getContent()); // Entire response body

        // See what other fun stuff you can do!:
        var_dump(get_class_methods($response));
    }
}
```

Your Controller/Route will work exactly as if you had called it using `curl`. Have fun!