# How to set cookie in custom command and get it in middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am looking for way to set cookie in console custom command and get it in middleware in Laravel(version - 5.2). This is what I am trying

In custom command,

```
Cookie::queue('login', 'true', 1);
$cookies = array('login' => true);
```

In middleware,

```
Cookie::get('login') // unable to get here set cookie
```

Calling route internally through custom command

```
$req = Request::create('/my/url', 'POST', $params, $cookies);
$res = app()->handle($req);
$responseBody = $res->getContent();
```

Reference
[symfony/http-foundation](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/7e7b3c05ff74dff2f049dc71e74b7f0c7ee1daf6/Request.php#L311-L324)
[calling-routes-internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472138/laravel-5-calling-routes-internally)

Your assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you have already created a `middleware`, suppose `CookieMiddlware`. So inside `CookieMiddlware` there is a handle method. There try to `dd($request);`.

For example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd($request);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

Register your middleware and then apply it on a route. Hit that route and you will see full request data. There you will find cookies. Open it and play with it.

If you have set the cookies properly you can get it from request in middleware.

```
+cookies: ParameterBag {#45 ▼
#parameters: array:3 [▼
  "laravel_session" => "FDyl3cnxEy3VDIiivxLQmDDbyZuJggeU8"
  "XSRF-TOKEN" => "7TQrk9QZKrpPPrgoaAXNOIZlThrePlesjQJ"
  "etc" => "2zbP5hem9RcvBcQwBz8UewwZxWQxQAcA4"
 ]
}
```

And you can access it like `$request->cookie('name');` something like that, I think you know the rest. It may help you.

Checked in this way.

```
$cookies = array('login' => "akhtar");
$ar = json_encode($cookies);
Cookie::queue('test',$ar,100);
dd(json_decode(Cookie::get('test')));
```

Comment: $cookies = array('testing' => 'sonam');
 Getting only key in middleware with null
 +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1130
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "testing" => null
    ]
  }

Comment: public static function create($uri, $method = 'GET', $parameters = array(), $cookies = array(), $files = array(), $server = array(), $content = null) as mentioned, it must be type of array. That's why when encoding in JSON getting fatal error

Comment: I know but when you are setting your cookies then make it `json_encode` and while accessing make it `json_decode`.

Comment: No change, getting null only

Comment: I have done it in this way just for testing and it works. See updated answer

Comment: If you are still getting null, then try to clear your cookies and then try again.

Comment: I am running custom artisan command through CLI, clear cache instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209835/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-sonam-tripathi).