# guzzlehttp/guzzle dosn't work after update php to php 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle, php-8

I use the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` package in **Laravel 8**. After upgrading to **PHP 8**, I get:

> `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Invalid opcode 117/2/0. in file ../vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php on line 412`

composer.json:

```json
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.12.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
      "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
```

`php -v`:

```
PHP 8.0.0RC3 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 17:06:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0RC3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

> **UPD 1** If I call `opcache_reset ();` before `$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client; $response = $this->client->post(...)`, it works.

> **UPD 2** `$ service php8.0-fpm reload` -  did not help.

> **UPD 3** Reboot server did not help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may need to invalidate the opcode cache using [opcache_invalidate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php) since you've just upgraded major php versions.

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: This site explains how for each php cli, fpm, etc: https://serverguy.com/magento/flush-php-opcache/

Comment: @DigitalDrifter update

Comment: If reloading the fpm service didn't resolve anything it may be that it's still pointing to a previous version of php-fpm. The fact that `opcache_reset` worked also leads me to think thats the case.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter and how can i fix this?)

Comment: That's a different topic entirely, if you want to post a new question with what you've discovered I'd be happy to keep helping, but it's important to keep posts succinct and focused to a single topic on this site.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034752/why-is-the-opcache-not-flushed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the opcache not flushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034752/why-is-the-opcache-not-flushed)

Comment: @JakeFreeman The same case when the answer is a new question) Now I will answer my own question.

Comment: This is not related to opcache flushing, it's a bug in PHP :)

Comment: @NikiC What mistake? And where?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error after upgrading to PHP8. @NikiC is there an open bug report for this if it's a bug in PHP?

Comment: @jdelaune No bug report for this, but the fix is https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fdb05b92bfb62906771fd41f3fcdbc184d89e3fe. Setting `opcache.optimization_level=0` should work as a temporary workaround.

Comment: @NikiC great thanks I will give that a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. The problem is, on **Ubuntu 20.10** **PHP8** does not clear the **opcache**. If you do `opcache_reset();` before calling `new \GuzzleHttp\Client;`, then everything works.

Comment: I have the same problem on macos bigsur

Answer (score 0):

As @NikiC said in the comments above it’s actually a bug in PHP. Fix here: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fdb05b92bfb62906771fd41f3fcdbc184d89e3fe

It is NOT a good idea to reset the opcache each time as you may as well not have any opcache if you are going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the version of php or  use this commend line (for php 8) and everything will be okay.

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.4