# Why is the opcache not flushed?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, php-8

I use the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` package in **Laravel 8**. After upgrading to **PHP 8**, I get:

> `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Invalid opcode 117/2/0. in file ../vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php on line 412`

`nginx` config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/finex_production/public/;

  index index.php;
  server_name ff.loc;
  
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
  }

  client_max_body_size 256M;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
}
```

**PHP 7.4 is removed**.

If I call `opcache_reset ();` before, I don't get error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with PHP League OAuth package. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @josephxanderson no( I'm waiting for patches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by temporarily setting `opcache.optimization_level=0` in `php.ini`.

Still according to [this post](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80519), it's a known bug which should be fixed in **PHP 8.0.1**