# Local http request with authorization

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-passport

I'm trying to query the passport `/oauth/clients` endpoint from my backend php and I am using this code

```
$response = Http::get(config('app.url') .'/oauth/clients');
```

where my `app.url` is set to `http://homestead.test` (for development purposes). If I navigate to that endpoint in my browser I get an array of clients as expected but as soon as I try to do this query from my backend and then dump the body like this `dd($response->body());` it just returns my website login page.

I'm assuming this is due to the session not being passed correctly as a header but if I dump `$response->headers()` I get a `Set-Cookie` header with my app session there.

I am currently using this code to get the clients array and it works, but I think it isn't the best way to get the array as it messes up the `Route`

```
$clientRequest = Request::create(config('app.url') .'/oauth/clients');
$response = Route::dispatch($clientRequest);

$clients = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```

Comment: Could you please share `/oauth/clients` route?

Comment: Seems like you may need to authenticate first: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#authentication

Comment: @hcphoon Does your authentication exist in your browser? You could check this in `application` tab.

Comment: Did you add content type as application/json

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [Laravel 5: Calling routes internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472138/laravel-5-calling-routes-internally)?

1. You can try to instantiate your controller and call the method behind the route.
2. You can use app()->handle($req) like erwan wrote.

But if that fails, using Route::dispatch seems ok.