# when I create a new request in middleware, it overwrites initial request in controller

Tags: php, request, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

in the middleware I need to create new internal request, get the response and change the initial request.
This is the code I use in the middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    // I create new request
    $newRequest = Request::create('internal url');
    $newRequest->setMethod($method);
    $newRequest->merge([
        'temp_param_1' => 'value',
        'temp_param_2' => 'value',
    ]);
    $response = app()->handle($newRequest);
    $mixedResponse = json_decode($response->getContent(), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    // Now I add new parameter to initial request
    $request->merge([
        'new_value' => 'new_value',
        'new_value_1' => $response['new_value_id']
    ]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now, in the controller, If I use this code:

```
public function index()
{
    Log::info($request->all());
}
```

I expect to have `new_value` and `new_value_1` in the log, instead I have `temp_param_1` and `temp_param_2`.
It seems the new request I create in middleware overwrites initial request.

Comment: What does `app()->handle($newRequest);` do?

Comment: I get code from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472138/laravel-5-calling-routes-internally